# How to edit certain part of char array

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any function or method in c to do swap/edit of certain part of char array.

Some pseudocode:

```
char A[] = {"/text/X/text/Y","/text/G/text/H"};
int VAL[] = {0,1,2,3};

swap/edit -> set X to VAL[0],set Y to VAL[1],set g to VAL[2],set H to VAL[3]
```

Comment: No. You can use `strtok()` to split source string into chunks and save these chunks as array elements

Comment: Note that your declaration of `A` won't compile as it has an incomplete type. Should it be one or two dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to specify what you're looking for (the `needle`s) in the haystack (`A`).
`strstr()` finds a pointer to the needle, if it exists in the haystack. Since your replacement values are `int`, not `char` or `char[]` (or a pointer to those types), you need to use `sprintf`/`snprintf` to save a formatted string into your variable.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {   
    char A[] = {"/text/X/text/Y/text/G/text/H"};
    int VAL[] = {0,1,2,3};
    char needle[][2] = {
        {"X"},
        {"Y"},
        {"g"},
        {"H"}
    };

    printf("Original A: %s\r\n", A);
    //swap/edit -> set X to VAL[0],set Y to VAL[1],set g to VAL[2],set H to VAL[3]
    for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(VAL)/sizeof(int)); i++) {
        char *p = NULL;
        p = strstr(A, needle[i]);
        if(p) snprintf(p, 1, "%1i", VAL[i]);
    }
    printf("Edited A: %s\r\n", A);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Original A: /text/X/text/Y/text/G/text/H
Edited A: /text/0/text/1/text/G/text/3
```

Comment: You forgot that snprintf puts \0 after VAL is added... So that doesnt work

Comment: I tested it in gdb and only `A[28] == 0`. That's why the whole array prints with just one `%s` format specifier.